# d3 Collapsible Tree Layout different node images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I've got a collapsible tree in d3.js. My goal is to fit different images into the nodes from the some node attribute. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Have you attempted to write this yourself at all? If not, try to write it and *then* post your code here if you get stuck.

Comment: I tryed to do it by css, e.g.:
<circle r="14" style="background: url(img/1.jpg);"></circle>
but it does not work. Image is not visible.